# websocket in c# for windows forms

Tags: c#, websocket

I have a question regarding c# form development using Websocket. I have an application that need to communicate with itself using Websocket client/server implementation. I am using websocket4net for client side and written code for server side. when I use "ws://127.0.01:8080" as uri for Websocket client it works. but when I change the uri to "xxx.xx.xx" for the public ip address of my computer it doesn't. Can Web Socket for windows form can be used to communicate with the same app residing on different machine?

Here is the code I used to connect as a client:

```
WebSocket websocket = new WebSocket("ws://xxx.xxx.x.xx:8080/");
websocket.Open();
```

Regards,
Muhammad

Comment: Is port 8080 forwarded to your machine?

Comment: Yes, I have also added the rules to allow communication over TCP.

Comment: Try starting the client on another machine within your same network and then connect to your server using your internal IP address. See if that works. If so, then I would have a look at your routing rules.

Comment: yes, I tried with internal IP and it did work. are routing rules same as firewall rules can you elaborate on what routing rules are?Are they firewall rules.If so, I changed it already for port 8080 and it didn't work.

Comment: The routing rules are set at the router which is the gateway for your network. The discussion of which is far beyond the comment section. Have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) and then find your individual router's help pages on the internet. Good luck!

Comment: make sure you test with telnet that the connection is indeed open on that port over the internet

Comment: I used telnet xxx.xx.xx 8080 and it gives me black screen, which means its connecting